# How to patch a starred environment

Tags: macros, floats, horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, patching

I would like to translate [my approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables/2652#comment696035_2652) to center all `figure` environments to `figure*` environments. How?

```
\documentclass[peerreview]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \def\figure{\def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\normalsize\@setminipage\@IEEEfiguretopskipspace}\@float{figure}}
\patchcmd{\figure}{\normalsize}{\normalsize\centering}{}{error}
% \@namedef{figure*}{\def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\normalsize\@setminipage\@IEEEfiguretopskipspace}\@dblfloat{figure}}
% \patchcmd{\figure*}{\normalsize}{\normalsize\centering}{}{error}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        centered!
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure*}[t]
        not centered!
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The straightforward approach up there does not work, probably due to the use of `\@namedef` instead of `\def`.

Comment: The reference to `\@nameref` is completely irrelevant, in my point of view

Comment: Yes, I changed the title of the question already. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I meant the reference to `\@nameref` in the new title ;-)

Comment: actually, a better title would be "how to patch a starred *environment*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to patch an environment such as `figure*` you can do

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname figure*\endcsname{....}{...}{}{}
```

This method is ineffective with commands such as `\section*`, which are defined in a completely different way.

On the other hand, if you just want to add `\centering` to all floats, you can just add `\centering` to `\@floatboxreset`:

```
\makeatletter
\appto{\@floatboxreset}{\centering}
\makeatother
```

This will influence also `table` and other floats, though.

Comment: Thanks! Knowing now that the star may be the culprit, I wonder how long it takes until someone shows me dozens of duplicates for this simple question...

Comment: You could probably mention that this method only works for starred _environments_  like the example of `figure*`  even though the question title talks of _commands_ (`\section*` for example is rather different, as you know:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was from the phone.